# How to change loss matrix in XGboost (in R)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I want to classify a binary variable with cost of a false positive higher than a false negative.

In `rpart` package we use the loss matrix , adding `parms = list(loss=matrix(c(0,1,5,0),nrow=2))` for the cost of mis-classifying a negative example as positive is 5 times higher than the cost of mis-classifying a positive example as negative.

How can I do that with `XGboost` ?

Comment: you have to incorporate loss matrix it into custom loss function bith feval parameter

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `scale_pos_weight` parameter?

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md

> scale_pos_weight, [default=1] Control the balance of positive and
>   negative weights, useful for unbalanced classes. A typical value to
>   consider: sum(negative cases) / sum(positive cases) See Parameters
>   Tuning for more discussion. Also see Higgs Kaggle competition demo for
>   examples: R, py1, py2, py3

You can use it something like:

```
clf = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='binary:logistic', 
                       scale_pos_weight= 5,
                       max_depth=3,
                       n_estimators=100)
```

in python, sklearn api.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using [xgboost](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/index.html) package You can use `watchlist` parameter. It is a list of `xgb.DMatrix`, each of them tagged with a name. You can use eval.metric parameter, multiple evaluation metrices are also allowed.

```
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain, test=dtest)

bst <- xgb.train(data=dtrain, max.depth=2, eta=1, nthread = 2,
eval.metric = "error", eval.metric = "logloss", nround=2,
watchlist=watchlist, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

If the extensive list of metrices in [xgboost github pages](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) does not suffice your need then as they say you can generate you own metrices, eg a weighted sum of false positive and false negative where false positive is weighted five times more than the false negative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to change the metrices but how the trees are built. In `rpart` package, you can specify that the cost for false positives is different than the cost of false negatives when create tree nodes.
This is what I want to do but with `xgboost`.